# Save multiple Variables with Google play games

Tags: c#, serialization, save, cloud, google-play-games

I am currently setting up a wild system for a mobile game in unity thanks to the google play games plugin.

I have currently managed to save a value through the tutorial provided here: http://resocoder.com/2017/03/10/gpg-tutorial-saved-games-code/

But I can not manage to save a larger number of variables.

I would like according to the code above to be able to return not a float, but a table of value.

Someone would have an idea of how I can do it please? And if you do not know, would you be kind enough to explain to me how does the serialization or deserialization of data in tables [] byte?

Thank you

Comment: Using the built-in [BitConverter class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) you can convert back and forth between an array (1-dimensional table) of doubles and a byte array. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: more than just transforming an int datatype into byte type in an array i am looking to modify the code above to be able to save a variable list instead of a single variable.

Currently the code allows to save a single variable that names it "CloudVariables.Highscore" and it works, but I would like for example save, "CloudVariables.Highscore" and "CloudVariables.Power" and I do not see how to do it for that .

The "GameDataToString ()" function only returns "CloudVariables.Highscore", and I do not know how this function can return two variables.

Comment: And this is valid in the other way the function "StringToGameData" compares and transforms data backup to reassign them to "CloudVariables.Highscore" And I would like to make sure that the data backup is reassign to full of different variable and in the good order.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question but, for the future this answer should be useful.

Unity have Json support hereafter UnityEngine.JSONSerializeModule.
So we can keep a little more data with GPGS without 3rd party packages.

You can crate a class for your all data. (Thee deep of data length should less than 7 floor)

```
   using UnityEngine;
public class Try : MonoBehaviour
{
    string theDataWhichWillSendToCloud;
    public MyData saveJson;
    public void JsonToString()//BeforeSave
    {
        theDataWhichWillSendToCloud = JsonUtility.ToJson(saveJson);
    }
    public void StringToJson()//AfterLoad
    {
        saveJson = (MyData)JsonUtility.FromJson<MyData>(theDataWhichWillSendToCloud);
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class MyData
{
    [SerializeField] private float health;
    [SerializeField] private float money;
    public float Health { get { return health; } set { health = value; } }
    public float Money { get { return money; } set { money = value; } }
}
```

Finally when you want to save data, Call JsonToString()
when you load, after the load re-set the data from string with StringToJson()